# How many extrema has $f(x)$ from $L^2$ if it is not a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Is it possible to say how many extrema the $L^2$ function

$
f(x)=A\text e ^{-(x+\lambda)^2} - B\text e ^{-x^2} + C\text e ^{-(x-\lambda)^2}
$

has on whole $\mathbb R$? Here $A$, $B$, $C$ and $\lambda$ are real positive constants. I guess maximal 3 extrema.

For a polynomial it is easy to say but I don't know any rule for such a function...

Comment: Implicit function theorem?

Comment: hm, I don't understand how I can use the implicit function theorem to find out the _number_ of extrema...

Comment: if you can show that the roots of the derivative vary continuously with its parameters, then you can find the number of extrema in one case and "follow" all roots back to them.

Comment: thx for your help. can you please explain what you mean with "follow all roots back to them"? I thought the Implicit function theorem just tells me when I can solve $f'_{\lambda}(x_0)=0$ for $x_0$. Then I have to check if this implizit function $x_0(\lambda)$ varies continuously with $\lambda$? But how to count then the extrema?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem. What I know is that you can prove that the roots of a polynomial vary continuously with their coefficients. In some cases you can do this with the implict function theorem--remember the theorem gives continuity of an implicitly defined function. If you research these proofs or facts, it may reveal a technique to solve this problem.

Comment: If also learn the proof of the Gershgorin theorem (a theorem about the eigenvalues of a matrix) you may find a useful technique there as well.

Answer (score 0):

We write $$f'(x)=-2xAe^{-x^2-2x\lambda -\lambda^2}+2xBe^{-x^2}-2xCe^{-x^2+2x\lambda-\lambda^2}$$
or 
$$f'(x)=-2xe^{-x^2}(A'e^{-2x\lambda}+C'e^{2x\lambda}-B)$$
where now $A'=Ae^{-\lambda^2}, C'=Ce^{-\lambda^2}$.

Since the sign of $-2xe^{-x^2}$ is known, what is needed is to know how many sign changes $$g(x)=A'e^{-2x\lambda}+C'e^{2x\lambda}-B$$ can have.  The answer is infinitely many.  For example,  if $\lambda=\sqrt{-1}$, $A'=C'=1, B=0.1$, since $\cos x=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$.

Comment: But $\lambda$ is also real and positive. I think in your example it is easy to see that there are inifinite sign changes... but for real $\lambda$ is is not easy to see that there are maximal 3 extrema.

Comment: $\lambda>0$ was not in the original problem statement.

Comment: This is a good point, but feels like taking the easy way out. The intuition is that the function for real values must have at most three extrema, but what is an easy way to prove this?