# Methods to distinguish continuous probability distributions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, statistics, probability-distributions

I read in the Wikipedia article for [Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)

> The variance is one of several descriptors of a probability distribution. In particular, the variance is one of the moments of a distribution. In that context, it forms part of a **systematic approach to distinguishing between probability distributions**. **While other such approaches have been developed**, those based on moments are advantageous in terms of mathematical and computational simplicity.

I am very interessted in methods to distinguish continuous probability distributions. Especially to distinguish analytically if the distribution has two distinct peaks or just one.

Does someone know what is meant with "While other such approaches have been developed"?

Comment: Is an approximate solution acceptable ? (When two maxima are close to each other, does it matter to know for sure if they merge or not ?)

Comment: To be honest: At the end it is just important for the two peaks to be visible to the naked eye. There is no mathematical criterion. The main goal is to find a mathematical criterion for the statement "to be visible to the naked eye". I think it is quite good to use the variance and the kurtosis...

Answer (score 1):

See

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29#Variance)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function

here the moment generating function completely determined the random variable. But the moments are not, as there are different random variables with identical moments. So the first and second moment (or the variance and the mean) is still a very weak invariant.

Comment: Thanks. But the biggest problem for me is that the moments sometimes do not exist (e.g. for a Cauchy distribution). Thats the weak point of this method to distinguish continuous probability distributions.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a bimodality test. Read  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimodal_distribution.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I have a general continuous probability distribution in the sence of an abstract mathematical function $f(x)$ which depends on some parameters and another given continuous probability distribution. So I have nothing to do with concrete data. I glimpsed through the wikipedia article and it seems that most of the presented methods are applicable only when you have concrete data which you want to analyse. The only analytical thing I found in this article was _kurtosis_ and _skewness_. But this is actually nothing but the good old approach via the cumulants.

Comment: I didn't believe that you were looking for a solution for analytically known distributions. Can't you count just the extrema ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. For a simplified example see [my question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815371/how-many-extrema-has-fx-from-l2-if-it-is-not-a-polynomial). Anyway, the reminder for kurtosis and skewness does help already.

Comment: You could have stated from the beginning that the question relates to mixture of three Gaussians - possibly trimodal.

Comment: No this was just a particular example. Since I was not able to find a general criterion I tried to play around with concrete examples...

Comment: I really doubt that you will find a general multimodality criterion based on moments or other indirect features computation. The direct question is "how many roots in the first derivative" ? Unfortunately, we have no really better approaches than trial and error for root separation of transcendent functions.

Answer (score 1):

If a rough detection suffices, I suggest this elementary scheme:

- find the interesting range of the variable (delimit the tails),
- evaluate the distribution at equally spaced points, using the smallest distinguishable separation (say 100 points),
- report any maximum configuration $f_{n-1}\lt f_n\gt f_{n+1}$.

More sophisticated schemes can be used to find changes of sign of the derivative, like [finite differencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficients) and root finding, but I am not sure they will bring any benefit.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I realise that my question was to imprecise. Unfortunately I have general parameters in my function, so there is no way to decide whether we are at a maximum.

Comment: If you need a solution in parameter space, then you should look at the limiting cases when two maxima merge. These correspond to the simultaneous canceling of the first and second derivatives.